# A Number Pattern Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence

I can't crack this one. Any help is appreciated,

[image: 1]

Comment: Please attribute your puzzle's source.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a source. A friend just handed me this exact scrap of paper!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> 261___253
>      ___ 10 ____
>      269___261

explanation:

> The center cell increased by one, then the blank cell in the next pattern is a sum of numbers that previously surround the cell. For example top left 10 in the second pattern is from 1+5+4, and bottom right 10 in the second pattern is from 2+3+5.

Comment: noooooooooo! i was making an answer.......         cruel world......